# Suggestions for how to store a number of pandas data frames for caching

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pickle

I currently have a script that runs a large SQL query against a DB and returns the results in a pandas dataframe and graphs the values. I currently store that dataframe using `pickle` in order to cache it for quick rerunning and debugging of code.

I now have to develop it to run around 20 queries and output 20 graphs. Are there any good suggestions on how to store 20 dataframes, from a results caching point of view for debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pickle` is definitely a good way to go. If you compare the performance and file sizes for different methods, you'll see that `pickle` is quite ok (using `%timeit` in `IPython`):

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////home/user/testdb.db')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000000), index=range(1000000))

# pickle, file size 23 MB
%timeit ts.to_pickle('p.test')
1 loops, best of 3: 279 ms per loop

# sql via sqllite, file size 33 MB
%timeit ts.to_sql('ts1', engine, if_exists='replace')
1 loops, best of 3: 11.9 s per loop

# json, file size 22 MB
%timeit ts.to_json('p.json')
1 loops, best of 3: 261 ms per loop
```

The overhead of `sqlite` makes it quite slow, and just for caching you won't benefit (especially if your data is in another SQL database anyway...).

You might actually consider testing `json` for your purpose, it has about the same speed as `pickle`, but you could read the `json`ed data with other programs (plotting with `d3` for example).